# Map JSON from MyBatis database

Tags: java

I am using myBatis to connect to a DB2 database . We have values stored in JSON format in the database .
Is there any way I can retrieve the values from the database and map the JSON values directly to a POJO using a mapper?
Currently we take it as a String and parse it later on .

Comment: Yes we can retrieve the values from the database and map the JSON values directly to a POJO using a mapper

Comment: I was asking this specific to the mapper used with MyBatis .

Answer (score 0):

You can use jackson. You can add it to your project with maven, and then use it easily.

You should have a look here 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

And here :
http://websystique.com/java/json/jackson-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Those links might help you.